# Joining to a GROUP'ed query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm a LINQ Newb and I've got this query, which returns the pages in a survey. (These values are not materialized into a table, for whatever reason.)

```
//Group all of this data by page 
var pages = from fq in db.FormQuestions
        where (fq.FormId == id) && fq.Disabled == false
        group fq by fq.PageNumber into p
        select new DTOs.PageDTO { PageNumber = p.Key.Value };
```

And then I have this query, which projects all of the leaf-data into DTOs.

```
var questions = from fq in db.FormQuestions
   join q in db.Questions on fq.QuestionId equals q.QuestionId
   where (fq.FormId == id) && fq.Disabled == false
   //where (fq.FormId == id) && fq.Disabled == false && fq.PageNumber == page
   orderby fq.DisplayOrder
   select new DTOs.FormQuestionDTO()
   {
       DisplayOrder = (fq.DisplayOrder.HasValue ? fq.DisplayOrder.Value : 0),
       PageNumber = (fq.PageNumber.HasValue ? fq.PageNumber.Value : 0),
       QuestionId = q.QuestionId,
       QuestionSelectionMode = q.vts_tbQuestionSelectionMode.Description,
       QuestionText = q.QuestionText,
       Answers =
           from answer in q.Answers
           join at in db.AnswerTypes on answer.AnswerTypeId equals at.AnswerTypeID
           where answer.Disabled == false
           orderby answer.DisplayOrder
           select new DTOs.AnswerDTO()
           {
               AnswerId = answer.AnswerId,
               AnswerText = answer.AnswerText,
               DisplayOrder = answer.DisplayOrder,
               AnswerType = at.Description
           }
   };
```

Is there a way to join these two neatly? I.e., under each page DTO I want to see the QUestion DTOs, then inside of that Answer DTOs, and onward...

Also, even if I could do this all in one LINQ statement, is it preferable to build the LINQ statements separately and then merge them? This feels a bit like building temp variables in SQL in that it may be possible to build one giant query but it's a pain to maintain.

Comment: What do you mean "inside"?

Comment: Each page object would in turn contain questions and each question would contain answers. Eventually this is outputted as a hierarchical JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why wouldn't something like this work?

```
//Group all of this data by page 
var pages = from fq in db.FormQuestions
        where (fq.FormId == id) && fq.Disabled == false
        group fq by fq.PageNumber into p
        select new DTOs.PageDTO { 
          PageNumber = p.Key.Value 
          questions = from fq in db.FormQuestions
                     join q in db.Questions on fq.QuestionId equals q.QuestionId
                     where (fq.FormId == id) && fq.Disabled == false
                     orderby fq.DisplayOrder
                     select new DTOs.FormQuestionDTO()
                     {
                       DisplayOrder = (fq.DisplayOrder.HasValue ? fq.DisplayOrder.Value : 0),
                       // etc as you 2nd code sample
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how you then join in the answers? I tried something like this at one point and I think hit a snag. But it could for all I know.

Comment: This is joining the answers -- I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: Thank you! While I have you, is there any way to add an optional predicate to a linq query? I.e., let's say the method has an optional page number parameter because we want to either limit the query to the specified page, or if none is supplied, return all pages. In a sql sproc I could add conditional logic while building part of the statement. Can that be done in LINQ?

Comment: @Jelling - There are some tricks you do in some cases... just as with SQL.  I'd more detail to answer a specific case.  Probably worthy of a new question.